# Toggle buttons bar for mobile?

Tags: mobile-web

I am designing filter interface that is located at the bottom of the screen of a smartphone.

I do not know if it's better to leave some space between the buttons (see the top of the attached image - preflop action), or leave the buttons without spacing/border (see bottom of the attached image - preflop position)

Is one button being selected enough indication of where a user is supposed to click to change the option, or is additional spacing needed?

Some additional info:

- One of the options is always selected
- Only one of the options can be selected
- Hover to show button borders does not work since this is targeting smart phones and tablets

[image: Both toggle buttons options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button border helps user to centre touch points on a button. Though, text label does the same thing, but a border makes it explicit specially to avoid confusion if there are two words in a button (you don't have that in your example). Better test with users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an intermediate design between both options using thin strokes.

[image]